# A Glutton and a Split Check

Tags: mathematics, strategy, game-theory

**N**, **T**, **A**, **B** are arbitrary constants in this problem. I have only definitively solved the **N=1** subproblem, so, if the general problem cannot be solved, I will be satisfied to mark as accepted a solution to this subproblem. I may put a bounty out for the general solution before that.

### Problem Statement

You and **N** friends are seated at a restaurant, where you have agreed to equally split the check for \$**T**. The dining process consists of a waiter going around the table, asking each guest in turn to order an entrée costing any amount of \$1, \$2, ..., up to \$**A** (you cannot skip an entrée). The meal is of course over once the \$**T** limit has been reached (it cannot be exceeded).

The vain glutton that you are, you want to:

1. eat more than you pay for (that is, \$**T/(N+1)**), but also;
2. not be exposed as a glutton, which in this case consists of eating more than \$**B** extra than the next most expensive eater. If (1) cannot be achieved, you will nonetheless consider it a victory to see someone *else* exposed in such a fashion.

Assuming you are first to order, for what values of **N**, **T**, **A**, **B** can you guarantee victory, no matter how your friends order? Keep in mind, they may conspire to make it difficult for you...

### Example

If **(N, T, A, B) = (1, 21, 13, 10)**, your gluttony might tempt you to order the most expensive \$13 entrée right off the bat. This would be a mistake, because your friend could thereafter order only \$1 entrées and expose you as a glutton. Similarly, you shouldn't order an \$11 or \$12 entrée. Yet if you order a $10 entrée or less, your friend may order an \$11 entrée, and you wind up paying for more than you eat while he cannot be exposed. So, there is no victory in this example configuration.

Comment: Are you the first to order?

Comment: Yes, it says so in the least paragraph of Problem Statement :)

Comment: Funny, N>1 case seems easier than N=1, because the other's don't have to worry about being exposed (unless b=0). Still, too many cases for me  ;-)

Comment: Reminds me of this a little bit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_game

Comment: If the waiter gets all your orders and the check amount T is not reached (like in your example) does he start another round? If not, do you want to still eat for at least T/(n+1) or only for (total check)/(n+1)?

Comment: @Petr Naryshkin He will go around the table as many times as it takes to reach a total check of T, yes.

Comment: Hmm I just re-read the question and I'm a bit confused. How are they "equally splitting the check for \$T" if by the definition of the rest of the problem some people are ordering food that costs more than others' orders? Is everyone spending \$T/N regardless of how much they ordered for? If so, then not sure I understand \$T/(N+1) -- if everyone is spending \$T/N then aren't you "eating more than you pay for" starting from orders worth \$(T/N)+1 or more, rather than \$T/(N+1)? Are the parentheses applied incorrectly in the problem statement?

Comment: You have N friends, so, there are N+1 people in total who have precommitted to splitting the $T check. What they have not decided in advance is who is ordering what.

Comment: @Feryll Ah sorry, missed that N was your friends, not the number of people at the table. I see now the problem statement clarifies that. Thanks!